# Contexto para tradução: Cunha (wedge)

Tags: tradução, palavra-para-ideia

Estava traduzindo algumas frases quando vi essa:

> The secret behind John's bond with Jane is also the **wedge** that keeps them apart

Nunca havia ouvido ou lido a expressão destacada e quando traduzi vi que significava **cunha**. Outra palavra que nunca ouvi falar e que tem vários significados (mesmo!)

As duas talvez mais plausíveis, dado o contexto — John seria um tipo de líder, poderoso e influente e Jane seu braço-direito (e Jane tem relação própria e secreta com alguém da... "oposição") — seria **peso** ou **influência**:

> O segredo por trás da ligação de John com Jane também é o **peso** que os mantém separados

Ou:

> O segredo por trás da ligação de John com Jane também é a **influência** que os mantém separados

Mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Considerando que 'cunha' é um objeto utilizado para manter aberturas e/ou separações; acredito que a frase traduzida seria: "*O segredo da ligação de John com Jane é também a distância entre eles.*", pois *wedge* (cunha) é utilizado conotativamente. Faz sentido, pois é comum se dizer que algumas pessoas apenas se dão bem porque mantêm distância entre si.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concordo com o William, aqui *wedge* tem um significado claro de cunha como objeto que os mantém firmemente a uma certa distância.

Penso que a melhor tradução seria algo menos literal que "distância", algo mais figurativo, como o original "cunha".

Eu sugeriria:

> O segredo por trás da ligação de John com Jane também é a barreira que os mantém separados.

Comment: Minha irmã, que presta atenção fingindo que não presta (rs), entendeu principalmente o trecho entre parênteses que eu citei e, esclarecendo a posição dela, fiou assim: É como se a tal relação secreta (e não romântica, pra deixar claro) de Jane com essa pessoa da "oposição" já fosse de conhecimento de John. Assim, a relação de John com Jane é forte, mas que justamente por causa desse segredo dela, a relação pára por aí, digamos, não avança para algo mais íntimo entre eles. O que você diria? Isso poderia mudar a frase?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Eu diria que não é impressão que ganho da frase que você coloca: afinal o segredo por trás (ou seja, que explica/causa) a ligação forte entre eles é **também** (*also*) o que os separa. Ou seja, a ligação dela com o inimigo não é apenas algo que impede uma aproximação maior, mas ao mesmo tempo é o que atrai John a ela. Ou seja, essa relação dela com a oposição pode ser útil para ele, ou excitante, mas também repele (por exemplo, por diminuir a confiança).

Comment: É, então acho que fica "barreira" mesmo. Ou melhor, "obstáculo", soa mais bonito :p